# Select data using a Linq expression as sub expresion inside another Linq expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-expressions

We're using Entity Framework with dynamic Linq expressions to select data form the database, in which the following entities are defined:

```
public class Entity1
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Somedata1 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Somedata2 { get; set; }
  IList<EntityLink> LinkedEntities1 { get; set; }
}

public class EntityLink
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  Entity1 ent1 { get; set; }
  Entity2 ent2 { get; set; }
}
```

The entities `Entity1` and `Entity2` have an `n-n` relationship.

To dynamically select data form `Entity1` we use (where `selectExpression` is defined as `Expression<Func<Entity1, object>>`)

```
var selectExpression = await modelEntity1.GetSelectExpression(); // model for `Entity1`

return await dbcontext.Entity1
  .AsQueryable()
  .Where(g => ...)
  .Select(selectExpression)
  .ToListAsync();
```

But in another routine I want to use the same `selectExpression` to select the data from `Entity1` when enumerating the 'linked' records of `Entity2`:

```
var selectExpression = await modelEntity1.GetSelectExpression();

return await dbcontext.Entity2
  .AsQueryable()
  .Where(e2 => ...)
  .Select(e2 => new {
    Id = e2.Id,
    // etc.
    ChildData = e2.LinkedEntities1.Select(l => new {
      LinkId = l.Id,
      LinkData = l.ent1.Select(selectExpression), // <- Does not compile as no 'Select' method exists
    }),
  })
  .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? ("this isn't possible" is not very informative).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes, your right - I've updated the comment to note is cannot compile as the `Select` method doesn't exist - so I'm looking for something that is available/can be used.

Comment: `ent1` is not of type `IQueryable` but of type `Entity1` which doesn't have a `Select` {extension} method. Replace `l.ent1.Select(selectExpression)` by `selectExpression(l.ent1)`

Comment: @Orace That won't even compile.

Comment: @Servy you are right. That's what makes this question interesting : how to apply a select expression to a single object inside an expression.

Comment: @Servy, and you already give a response to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827053/361177

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and samples - for now we’ve duplicated the code to get the same result, but I’ll look in to this asa I have the time for it.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your query to actually include the child entities:

```
dbcontext.Entity2.Include(x=>x.LinkedEntities1)
```

Comment: Since I don't want to just include all data regarding the `LinkedEntities1`, but only the specific members returned using the `selectExpression`, this isn't an option.